# Cannot change CONTENT_TYPE to application/x-www-form-urlencoded in Android HTTP POST call

Tags: android, post, http-post, httpurlconnection, android-networking

Our server expects 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' content-type on POST calls but when I set the header to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', it returns a 400 Bad Request. Here's my code using HttpPost:

```
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse responseobj = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    InputStream is = null;
    HttpEntity entity = responseobj.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "utf-8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
```

Here's my code using HttpsUrlConnection:

```
    URL urlToRequest;
    urlToRequest = new URL(url);
    HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) urlToRequest.openConnection();
    String postParams = getEncodedPostParams(params);
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(postParams.getBytes().length);
    conn.setRequestProperty(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

    OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
    writer.write(postParams);
    writer.close();
    os.close();
    conn.connect();
```

Here's the request on Charles Proxy. You can see that although I have set the content-type to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' in both cases, the request content-type is 'application/json':

```
https://myurl/
Complete
400 Bad Request
HTTP/1.1
POST
application/json
```

Does anyone know why I cannot change the content-type? I know similar questions have been asked before on SO and I have tried all of them to no avail. Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't use:

```
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",....)
```

it worked for me.